# How to get input from user for Hashmap using Scanner

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

How to get input from user for `Hashmap` using scanner and print the respective hashmap?

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Map {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Integer a = in.nextInt();
            Integer b = in.nextInt();
            
            hmap.put(a, b);

            System.out.println(hmap.put(a, b));
        }

    }

}
```

I am not getting the desired output. I want to print what is inserted in `hmap`.

Comment: `System.out.println(hmap.get(a))`

Comment: What is it outputting, what did you expect it to output, and what do you want it to output?

Comment: @Hugo it prints null

Comment: i want to get a o/p entries of hashmap

Comment: i am getting nulll as o/p

Comment: Do you want `System.out.println(hmap);`?

Comment: i got the answer :instead of System.out.println(hmap.put(a,b)); i should use System.out.println(hmap);

Answer (score 2):

Change your `System.out.println` statement to,

```
System.out.println(hmap.get(a));
```

Comment: if the input is a=1 b=2..I want o/p as a {1,2} but if i use system.out.println(hmap.get(a)); it gives me o/p as 2

Comment: i got the answer :instead of System.out.println(hmap.put(a,b)); i should use System.out.println(hmap);

Comment: that equal to hmap.toString(). Your question was not clear buddy.  Read out this, http://www.careerbless.com/samplecodes/java/beginners/collections_ds/inertandretrieveMap.php

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to put data into a `HashMap` at runtime:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

class MapDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Integer a = in.nextInt();
            String b = in.next();

            hmap.put(a, b);
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> m : hmap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + m.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect this to do? It is wrong, why would you print `hmap.put(a,b)`

```
System.out.println(hmap.put(a,b));
```

Just take it out of the for loop and print it separately

```
 for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> pair: hmap.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(pair.getKey() + "->" + pair.getValue());
}
```

Comment: i got the answer :instead of System.out.println(hmap.put(a,b)); i should use System.out.println(hmap);

Comment: You would still have to take the print statement out of for loop otherwise you will have a case of re-printing the entire map for each new entry

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc for the HashMap util can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

To add a key/value pair to a HashMap you use `hashmap.put(x, y)`.

Using `hashmap.get(x)` at a later time will return y.

Edit: It looks like from other comments you are trying to have it print out both the key and the value. In the case that you are trying to print out all keys and values something like this may work.

```
hashMap.forEach((e, k) -> {
    System.out.println("E: " + e + " K: " + k);
})
```

If this is not your intended purpose I would strongly recommend reading over the method summary section of the javadocs.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Call {
    
    public static void main(String[] as) {
        getData();
    }

    public static void getData() {
        Map<Integer, String> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Shashank Pathak\nEnter number of character: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            Integer b = sc.nextInt();
            String c = sc.nextLine();

            hashmap.put(b, c);
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> mp : hashmap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("\n" + mp.getKey() + " " + mp.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this, And it is exactly the same as I want.

```
System.out.println("How many producs you want");
        int listOfItem = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Type the product name and quantity you want to purchace and get the bill");
        HashMap<Integer, String> products = new HashMap<>();
        while(listOfItem-- >0){
        products.put(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println(products);
```

[Output of above program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeyIR.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

class hash1 {
    void dic(){
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> hmap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        hmap.put(a,b);
        System.out.println(hmap);
    }
}
public class answer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        hash1 obj = new hash1();
        for(int z = 0;z < 3;z++){
            obj.dic();
        }





    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. Add an explanation.